# angular 5 with electron-packager

Tags: electron, angular5

I try to build my electron project to window app by using electron-packager but I get this error.

Failed to locate module "fsevents" from "/var/www/windowapp/electron-angular-project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/chokidar"

```
    This normally means that either you have deleted this package already somehow (check your ignore settings if using electron-packager).  Or your module installation failed.
```

Anyone know how to solve it and what happened to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here my 2 cent, I did a package that works without the error, but also avoids to add unnecessary files:

```
electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src
```

The electron-packager expect that you have already run run the angular build process:

```
ng build --prod
```

You can add this script in the `package.json`:

```
"electron-package": "ng build --prod && electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"
```

Then run:

```
npm run electron-package
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me try with this cmd

Answer (score 1):

With slight modification on the answer provided by Michael Denny `"electron-package": "ng build --prod && electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"` I'm able to package my electron angular 7 application. Please note, minor modifications might require on these commands, on a case to case to basis. In my case, the following command worked.

`"electron-package": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"`

**What is the change?**

Removed  `--ignore=/node_modules`
*Reason*: if I add this option while building, Ended up in `Module Not Found` Error

Added `--base-href ./`
*Reason*: Otherwise, Ended up with error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

With these two modifications, I'm able to package my electron angular 7 application. Size of the package is close to 100MB. I'm looking for a way to reduce this size.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where your app is, try run this command

```
electron-packager . --no-prune
```

More information about this commands can be found in here https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt

Comment: I can build my app too with --no-prune, but then it copies all the node_modules folder with also devDependencies and I don't want it. Without the --no-prune it should compile it just fine, why it is not?

Comment: ok in my case I simply did this to make a cleaner package: `electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src`

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the issue [#821](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/821)in electron-packager with removing optional platform specific dependencies (possibly only when running packager on Windows).

--no-prune solves the problem during development, but won't work for production.

Reverting to v11.2.0 also solves the issue.