# How to properly package Electron + Angular-cli 9?

Tags: javascript, electron-builder, angular-cli-v9

My question is because I have been seeing how to do it for a long time and the first few times it worked, but lately I have had many problems.

I have seen several Blogs on how to link Electron with Angular but it always happens to me that I have errors with the main.js in the loadURL

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'frontend',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });


    mainWindow.maximize();
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
            protocol: "file:",
            slashes: true
        })
    );

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
})
```

I have already made the changes that videos and [pages](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-electron) usually say about this as

Editing the package.json with `"main": "main.js",`

Put the dot in `<base href ="./">`

In angular.json projects> appName> architect> build> options> outputPath change it to `"outputPath":"dist",` without the project title

All of the above works until the time of packaging.

For what several mention using `"electron-packager":"^14.2.1",`

From a simpler command like

"packager": "electron-packager. --platform = win32 --out dist / --overwrite"

Where first of all, it generates an error with `pathname: path.join (__ dirname, 'dist / index.html'),` because it locates it somewhere else and I have to change dist / for src /

What the exe generates but at the moment of starting only the `<app-root> </app-root>` tag appears without the angular scripts, that is, an empty page

And others [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643270/angular-5-with-electron-packager) to create the package.json script like:

```
"electron-package": "ng build --prod && electron-packager. --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"
```

or

```
"electron-package": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager. --no-prune --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"
```

That the latter I think does not generate the index.html: c

Does anyone know a Definitive process with Anglar-cli and Electron?

Comment: where is your `main.js` stores? which folder?

Comment: @v.kostenko Out of the way, next to the package.json

Comment: in the ./ source

Comment: First of all I think you need to build you angular app with `--base-href ./` also be sure your `main` in package.json refers to correct path for main.js. Have you tried to build app in this way and then packaged it like `electron-packager . --platform=win32 --out dist`? Also, could you provide please the full error text in the case where you have to change dist to src

Comment: Do you mean like electron-packager . --base-href ./ --platform=win32 --out dist ?

Comment: No, like this `ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . --platform=win32 --out dist`

Comment: The error that I mean is **Not allowed to load local resource index.html**

Comment: And yeah I tried to use that command :c idk what happen